# Push/Pull files among Unix machines with private key on Windows

Tags: ssh, scp

I am operating across three systems:

- A remote Unix machine (let's call it Unix1), which stores some files
- A local Windows machine (let's call it win1), which stores the **private** key to Unix1
- A remote Unix machine (let's call it Unix2) which stores a process.

The process on Unix2 cannot be installed on Unix1. Ideally, I am trying to do the following:

- From Unix2, connect to Unix1 (using the private key on win1)
- Pull some files from Unix1 to Unix2
- Run a process on Unix2
- Push the output files from Unix2 to Unix1 (using the private key on win1)

What syntax would I need to follow here? The location of the private key is what's creating quite some issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

## bring key from windows to unix

from private key on windows, generate public key, copy both to unix2.

if using putty, use puttygen, then conversion, **export openssh key**

private key look like: (RSA being the type of key)

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCUAEAzrtuUOEMAN1vaX1GFBLoBiDba/AiIdfFkTFJeZtaKtiuIpS7
(...)
----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

public key look like

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3....abc user@hosts
```

## authorize user2 on unix1

assuming user1/user2 on unix1/unix2, from unix2

append content of public key to `authorized_keys` (on `~user1/.ssh` on unix1)

put private key to `id_rsa` in `~user2/.ssh` on unix2.

## copy file

```
 scp /some/file1.txt /some/file2.cmd user1@unix1:/distant/place
```

## run process

```
 ssh -l user1 unix1 /distant/place/file2.cmd
```

## bring back result

```
 scp user1@unix1:/distant/place/result.txt /some
```